# gitk: tree commit ordering. How to show branch commits consecutively

Tags: git

In my git repository, there are 4 developers working. We like to keep our git tree straight (without any merge commits), so we use fetch and rebase approach instead of pull (merge).

There are several branches in the repository. Development mainly happens in the master branch, and we only resolve critical bugs in other branches. There is no need to merge these branches. If we need some commits to go in several branches, we cherry pick them.

My problem is, whenever I do a commit to a branch other than master, if I open gitk and try to view the tree, this commit comes to the top of the tree. Since the branch was branched out from master branch a long ago, there is a long continuation line (gitk shows an arrow downwards). Due to this, the clarity of the tree reduces.

It would be better if gitk showed the branch commits consecutively (at the place where the branch branched out from the master), without bringing the latest commit to the top.

Following is an example of what I get. As you can see, there is a continuation line (red line) and this can be very long in my actual repo. Also, the commit 9 and 3 are shown in the bottom of the continuation line in my actual repo, so the repo commits are not shown consecutively.

[image]

Does anyone know a way to instruct gitk to display branch commits consecutively? Or any other tool which can show the tree like I want?

Comment: `gitk` actually runs `git log` and `git rev-list`, all of which sort; and `gitk` has its own handling for several ordering flags.  If `--topo-order` or `--date-order` does not do what you want, there may not be a way to do what you want.  (I have not thought hard enough about what you want to know if they would do that.)

Comment: @torek, I think `--topo-order` is the default since it didn't change the default ordering at all. `--date-order` didn't do what I need to do either.

Answer (score 1):

What you're showing in your graph is `--topo-order`, which only breaks first-parent chains between (potential) merge bases and shows those chains, I think, in order by latest tip.  I think you're asking for a "longest-chain-first" order, where it doesn't matter which chain has the most recent activity, only which one has the most total activity.  That, git doesn't have.

As a crude-but-effective workaround you can get a particular ancestry chain shown first among siblings by putting a new, nonce commit at the tip of it -- so if you want to see the master branch at the top,

```
git tag highlight/master-branch $(git commit-tree -p master master: </dev/null)
```